# Nav with JS (double open)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my JS code, this code active a div with megamenu but i can open 2 megamenu at the same time, i need when i have already clicked the current megamenu disappears for the second is active. You have an idea ?

```
$(function() {

  var menuVisible = false;

  $('.contentLink').click(function() {

        var office = $(this).attr('data-office');

        if (menuVisible) {
            $('#_' + office).hide();
            $(this).removeClass('on');
            menuVisible = false;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#_' + office).show();
            $(this).addClass('on');
            menuVisible = true;
        }

    });

});

<nav>
    <ul class="menu-links">
        <li><a data-office="events" class="contentLink">Events</a>
            <div class="megamenu center" id="_events">
                My mega menu events
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a data-office="articles" class="contentLink">Articles</a>
            <div class="megamenu center" id="_articles">
                My mega menu articles
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please do not put [solved] in your question. We all see you selected an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, add this line on your `click()` function to hide all megamenu before :

```
$('.megamenu').hide();
```

I've edit your code to simplify it :

```
$(function() {
  $('.contentLink').click(function() {
        $('.megamenu').hide();
        menu = $(this).next();
        if(menu.is(':visible')){
           menu.hide();  
        }else{
           menu.show();       
        }        
    });
});
```

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/quycjppe/7/)

Comment: Its work, thanks a lot. I have just modify "menu = $(this).next();" per "var menu = $(this).next();" for compatibility with my jquery version otherwise i have an error "menu is undefined" Thanks again :)